# Keep Button State Selected in UICollection view with horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I am following this example
I have added a button in the view

[image]
On selection the button image change to Green icon image.

How could I retain it using [**this**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2) example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had updated the existing code of your example to your requirement please find the below url for download the code and review it.

Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xsr4o88khyijun/HorizontalTables.zip?dl=0

**Highlight of the code which I had done it.**

1) Take the `NSMutableArray` *arrSelection property in `HorizontalTablesAppDelegate` class.
2) Fill the data of arrSelection in `ArticleListViewController_iPhone` class of `viewDidLoad` method.

```
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.articleDictionary.allKeys count]; i++)
    {                        
        HorizontalTableCell_iPhone *cell = [[HorizontalTableCell_iPhone alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416) tag:i];

        categoryName = [sortedCategories objectAtIndex:i];
        currentCategory = [self.articleDictionary objectForKey:categoryName];
        cell.articles = [NSArray arrayWithArray:currentCategory];

        if(i == 0)
            appDelegate.arrSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *arrSubData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(NSInteger j=0; j<currentCategory.count; j++)
            [arrSubData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

        [appDelegate.arrSelection addObject:arrSubData];
        [arrSubData release];

        [self.reusableCells addObject:cell];
        [cell release];
    }
```

3) On `HorizontalTableCell_iPhone` class of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
NSMutableArray *arrSelectionInfo = appDelegate.arrSelection[tableView.tag];
BOOL isSelect = [arrSelectionInfo[indexPath.row] boolValue];

if(isSelect)
    [cell.btnSelection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
else
    [cell.btnSelection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

And `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
NSMutableArray *arrUpdate = appDelegate.arrSelection[tableView.tag];
[arrUpdate replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To keep button state selected you need to store information of selection on a `dictionary` for the cell. So once cell is reloaded, you can apply selection setting based on information you have.

There is no direct way (even if there was you should now use that, as it will lead to memory abuse) to keep it selected all the time.